# Center-aligning text with imagettfbbox works properly only in development

Tags: php

**# Update**

The problem is with the production server, most likely because it uses old versions of GD and/or libPNG and/or FreeType.

Tried on Namecheap and SiteGround shared hosts, and the text won't center-align on both. Tried on Cloudways and it works.

Both Namecheap and SiteGround have the same old versions of the above-mentioned libraries, while Cloudways and my local development environment don't.

So, if you have a similar app like mine, make sure you check the production servers before buying. Just having libraries enabled is not enough.

**# End update**

I have a small PHP web app that generates a simple, fixed-size .png image with text, based on the user input.

I'm using the GD library with imagettfbbox and base64_encode for this.

Everything works fine, except the center-aligning (vertically and horizontally) on the production server.

Here's the center-aligning code that **works very well in development**, but **doesn't work properly in production**:

```
$bbox = imagettfbbox($fontSize, 0, $font, $text);

// where $im is $im = imagecreate(512, 512);
$imageWidth = imagesx($im);
$imageHeight = imagesy($im);
$x = ceil(($imageWidth - $bbox[2]) / 2);
$y = ceil(($imageHeight - $bbox[7]) / 2);
```

Here's how it shows in production:

[image]

In development, it's perfectly aligned in the center.

I tried removing `ceil()`, but nothing changes.

I also tried another code, but has the same problem, but this time in development as well, not only in production:

```
$textWidth = abs($bbox[2]) - abs($bbox[0]);
$textHeight = abs($bbox[5]) - abs($bbox[3]);
$imageWidth = imagesx($im);
$imageHeight = imagesy($im);
$x = ($imageWidth - $textWidth) / 2;
$y = ($imageHeight + $textHeight) / 2;
```

For the development environment, I'm using Vagrant with a Homestead box, which uses Ubuntu 18.04 and Apache with PHP 7.3.

The production environment uses Linux, Apache, PHP 7.3. GD (bundled) is enabled, as well as FreeType (v2.3.11).

I literally have no idea why is this happening in production. No idea where to even start looking.

Could something be missing from production that needs to be enabled?

Comment: 1)  It's a length calculation, it should be `$textWidth = abs($bbox[2] - $bbox[0]); $textHeight = abs($bbox[5] - $bbox[3]);`. 2) I'm quite sure that `imagettfbbox()` does not return a result precise to the pixel.

Comment: Tried it. It's the same issue, but now in development as well. The first piece of code (the one above the image) works perfectly in development. It center-aligns as it should, but it doesn't work in production, too. That's the weird part.

Answer (score 0):

Since this is an actual solution to my problem, I added it as an answer. Hopefully, it will help out others.

A support rep from Namecheap came up with a tweak for my initial code to make it work on their server. I assume that it should work on other hosts with similar issues (check the update from my question).

```
$imageWidth = imagesx($im);
$imageHeight = imagesy($im);
$rightX = $bbox[2] + $bbox[0];
$x = ceil(($imageWidth - $rightX) / 2);
$y = ceil(($imageHeight - $bbox[7]) / 2);
```

This won't work properly in local development now because it will add more space to the right, but it will fix the issue on production, on certain shared hosts, which is the important part.